# linux/htimer: compiler error due to unknown struct size

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel

One of the (kernel)headers I'm using,  will not compile due to an error from the following line of code(I'd rather not post the whole header since you can look it up @lxr.free-electrons.com and it's only 1 line that has a bug in it).

This is the problem(it uses a preprocessor macro):

DECLARE_PER_CPU(struct tick_device, tick_cpu_device);

The gcc compiler error is as follows:

**error: storage size of ‘per_cpu__tick_cpu_device’ isn’t known**

So the tick_device struct is defined but what seems to be the trouble here?

Comment: Followup:  The declaration of the preprocessor macro(in all caps)is in the <linux/percpu.h> header and is:  #define DECLARE_PER_CPU(type, name)  __typeof__(type) per_cpu__##name

Comment: hrmm, weird. I try to find the macro in the file you suggested, but it isn't there, perhaps in asm/percpu.h?

Comment: Pre-process the file with `-E`.  You can compile the kernel with `V=1` to see the exact command line.  Then replace the `-c` with `-E` and update the `-o` option to *my_file.P*.  Take a look for `per_cpu__tick_cpu_device`.  It seems like you have defined **tick_device** as something else.  The compiler seems to have ignored the *tick_device* struct; that is the size of *per_cpu__tick_cpu_device*.